# Getting information from my loaded DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

How can I get information from my datable?

I just want to get column from start to finish, and load them to textboxes.text.

```
ClienteHolder.IDCliente = Tabla.Rows[]?????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tabla.Rows[0]["mycolumnName"]
```

This is how you can refer to a single column. What do you mean by column from start to finish?

What are the controls that you wish to store each of the column's value in?

Answer (score 1):

generally, you access the tables collection of the dataset, then access the rows collection of the table.  Like this:

```
myDataSet.Tables[0] // you can also use the name of the table, instead of an integer 

myTable.Rows[ n ]   // this will give you the nth row in the table

myRow[ n ]          // this will give you the nth column in the row, you can use the
                    // name of the column instead of an integer
```

this will iterate through all the columns in all the rows from all the tables in the dataset.

```
foreach( DataTable curTable in myDataSet.Tables )
{
     foreach( DataRow curRow in curTable.Rows )
     {
          foreach( DataColumn curCol in Table.Columns )
          {
               object item = curRow[ curCol ];
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Rows property for a datatable is IEnumerable.  LINQ is the better way to go here, but here's the way I do it with a foreach loop (If I'm understanding your question correctly.)

> I just want to get column from start to finish, and load them to textboxes.text.

```
foreach(System.DataRow dr in Tabla.Rows)//iterate rows
{
    foreach(System.DataColumn dc in Tabla.Columns)  //iterate columns per row
    {
        textboxes.text = dr[dc].ToString();  //get object value at row,column
    }
}
```

LINQ would be lamda like and awesome, but alas, We don't use 3.x here yet so I'm stuck leaning on this method.